# socket http lua to set timeout

Tags: api, rest, lua, timeout

I am trying to create a function that can call REST with the http socket lua.
And I tried to set the timeout this way. But, when I run this function, the timeout is not running. How should I set the timeout?

```
local http = require "socket.http"
local socket = require "socket"
       
       local respbody = {} 
       http.request {
                     method = req_method,
                     url = req_url,
                     source = ltn12.source.string(req_body),
                     headers = 
                              {
                                ["Content-Type"] = req_content_type,
                                ["content-length"] = string.len(req_body),
                                ["Host"] = host,

                              },
            
                     sink = ltn12.sink.table(respbody),
                     create = function()
                         local req_sock = socket.tcp()
                         req_sock:settimeout(3, 't')
                         return req_sock
                     end,

}
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks like a correct way to set the timemout. What do you mean by "timeout is not running"? What is the actual behaviour, and what do you expect from it?

Comment: My point is that when I make an API call with a response time longer than 3 seconds, the connection will be closed. Sorry if my English is not good.

Comment: No worries, it's understandable. I guess that the call blocks for more than 3 seconds? How long? LuaSocket notes that there might be slight differences in time it actually takes to timeout the request (see first note [here](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#settimeout)). I ran your sample and it times out correctly.

Comment: However, I tried to make a call with a response time of more than 10 seconds, the call was not closed. I am confused why the call did not timeout. I think something is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [lua-http](https://github.com/daurnimator/lua-http).  I use it to call REST and works like a charm.  I am not an expert but, as far as I can tell, it is a good LUA http implementation.

You can set a two seconds timeout as simple as:

```
local http_client = require "http.client"
local myconnection = http_client.connect {
    host = "myrestserver.domain.com";
    timeout = 2;
}
```

Full documentation in [here](https://daurnimator.github.io/lua-http/0.2/).

Answer (score 0):

if I implement the example with my requirements, will it be like this? cmiiw

```
local http_client = require "http.client" 
local req_body = "key1=value1&key2=value2" 
local myconnection = http_client.connect { 
    method = "POST"; 
    url = "myrestserver.domain.com/api/example"; 
    host = "myrestserver.domain.com"; 
    source = req_body 
    headers = { 
       ["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
       ["content-length"] = string.len(req_body), 
    }, 
    timeout = 2; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LuaSocket implicitly set [http.TIMEOUT](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/4df569e9f867432f25f0bfbfa56b0962feb3326e/src/http.lua#L119) to the socket object.
Also you have to remember that socket timeout is not the same as request timeout.
Socket timeout means timeout for each operation independently. For simple case you can wait connection up to `timeout` seconds and then each read operation can take up to `timeout` seconds. And because of HTTP client read response line by line you get `timeout` seconds for each header plus for each body chunk. Also, there may be redirecions where each redirection is a separate HTTP request/response. If you use TLS there also will be hendshake after connection which also took several send/receive operation.

I did not use lua-http module and do not know how timeout implemented there.
But I prefer use modules like cURL if I really need to restrict request timeout.